# Не создается storage в sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

Всем доброго времени суток.
Не создается бд при помощи sequelize.js. Код следующий:

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const {sequelize} = require('./models');
const config = require('./config/config');

const app = express();
app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

require('./routes')(app)

sequelize.sync()
    .then(() => {
        app.listen(config.port);
        console.log(`Server startet on port:${config.port}`);
    })
```

**config/config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    port : process.env.PORT || 9000,
    db   : {
        database : process.env.DB_NAME || 'tabtracker',
        user     : process.env.DB_USER || 'tabtracker',
        password : process.env.DB_PASS || 'tabtracker',
        options  : {
            dialect : process.env.DIALECT || 'sqlite',
            host    : process.env.HOST || 'localhost',
            storage : './tabtracker.sqlite'
        }
    }
}
```

**models/index.js**

```
const fs        = require('fs');
const path      = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const config    = require('../config/config');

const db = {};

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.db.database,
    config.db.user,
    config.db.password,
    config.db.options
);

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter((file) => {
        file !== 'index.js'
    })
    .forEach((file) => {
        const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
        db[model.name] = model;
    });

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;



module.exports = db
```

**models/User.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    sequelize.define('User', {
        email    : {
            type    : Sequelize.STRING,
            unique  : true
        },
        password : Sequelize.STRING
    });
}
```

**controllers/AuthenticationController.js**

```
const {User} = require('../models');

module.exports = {
    async register (req, res) {
        try {
            const user = await User.create(req.body);
            res.send(user.toJSON());
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(400).send({
                error: `This E-mail account is already in use${err}`,
            })
        }
    }

}
```

**Если отправлять POST через Postman, он выдает ошибку:**(Вводимые данные ситуацию не меняют)

```
"error": "This E-mail account is already in useTypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined"
```

**routes.js**

```
const AuthenticationController = require('./controllers/AuthenticationController');

module.exports = (app) => {
    app.post('/register',
        AuthenticationController.register)
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  ***

  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon src/app.js",
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*.js"
  },

  ***

  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5",
    "sequelize": "^4.8.0",
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-standard": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^6.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Терминал ругается, говорит что:

```
sequelize deprecated String based operators are now deprecated. Please use Symbol based operators for better security, read more at http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:242:13
```

Я посмотрел эти самые доки, но не врубился, где там менять нужно String based operators.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить это вот все?

Comment: У вас при импорте `const {User} = require('../models');` переменная `User` равна `undefined`. Значит что-то не так с экспортом. Попробуйте немного поменять экспорт, создайте переменную с функцией и в конце присвойте ей `module.exports = User;` а также поставьте точку останова на строке `const user = await User.create(req.body);` и удостоверьтесь в том, что `User` имеет значение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в вашем  комментарии к моему ответу, вы не написали ошибки из терминала, могу тогда предположить что:

1. не корректно отработала библиотека sqlite3
2. не корректно установился пакет sqlite3, у вас версия 3.1.8, а я установил версию 4.0.0 но я устанавливал командой **yarn add sqlite3** (запускать в папке **server**)
3. где то ошибка в коде из уроков

по 1 и 2 пунктам есть способ проверки

создайте в папке **server** файл **db.js**
в него вставьте этот код --

```
let sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();    
let db = new sqlite3.Database('mydb.sqlite3')    
db.serialize(function () {
  db.run('CREATE TABLE user(id INT, dt TEXT)')
})    
db.close()
```

откройте терминал в папке **server** и запустите команду

**node db**

в папке **server** должен появится файл **mydb.sqlite3**, внутри будет 'абракадабра' но это нормально, a если не появился, значит проблема в либо в библиотеке sqlite3, либо в пакете npm sqlite3 (смотрите пункт 2)

возможно нужно будет еще раз установить библиотеку sqlite3 этой командой

**sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev**

вот на всякий случай инструкция

https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=28&id=2277

Answer (score 0):

Прохожу этот же плейлист на youtube. База создается уже на 14:21 в терминале у автора в видео №2 видно сроку 
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Users ....
и в папке server должен появится файл tabtracker.sqlite

*Терминал ругается, говорит что: ... - -- у меня такая же строка выскакивает, но все работает и в Postman тоже все работает

База sqlite3 не создается, скорее всего, потому что вы не установили библиотеку sqlite3 на свой компьютер, если у вас Linux то в терминале запустите команду

**sudo apt install sqlite3**

для проверки установки введите

**sqlite3**

покажет версию и т.д., для выхода введите

**.quit**

Comment: Установил sqlite, все норм, но база все равно не создается